How can I get annotate field using child model in Django?
I have problem with getting Annotate field in Django(DRF).
For example, there are two models called AA, BB.
class AA(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class BB(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(AA, related_name="BB")
   name2 = models.CharField()

Then, I want to get the list AA, with annotate field called status.
The status condition is word(provided by client)=name2 For example,
[
  {
     name: "aaa1",
     status: True,  // if "aaa1" in AA has the word
  },
  {
     name: "aaa2",
     status: False,  // if "aaa2" in AA doesn't have the word
  }
]

So I coded like following code in views.py,
queryset = (AA.objects.prefetch_related("BB").annotate(
            status=Case(
               When(BB__name2=word, then=Value(True)),
               default=Value(False),
               output_field=BooleanField()
               )
            ))

but the following results came out. (If the word is "bbb1")
[
  {
     name: "aaa1",
     status: True,  // "bbb1" whose parent is "aaa1"
  },
  {
     name: "aaa1",
     status: False,  // "bbb2" whose parent is "aaa1"
  },
  {
     name: "aaa1",
     status: False,  // "bbb3" whose parent is "aaa1"
  },
  {
     name: "aaa2",
     status: True,  // "bbb1" whose parent is "aaa2"
  }
]

I want to know if even one child model(BB) has name2 from a parent(AA)'s point of view, and it returned a list of all children.
What should I do?

Solved with Exists and OuterRef in annotate.
queryset = (AA.objects.annotate(
               status=Exists(
                  BB.objects.filter(parent=OuterRef("id"), name2=word)
               )
            ))

